# return separate result for each relation in many to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi i have a many to many relationship with the following structure:

```
services
apps
service_app
```

I would like to have an eloquent query to return a separate result for each relationship(basically the pivot table). I have the following :

```
 $all = App::with('services')->get();
```

this will return an app with nested services, I would like to have this return a separate result for each app-service combination along with data from the pivot table. how is this possible using eloquent?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$all = App::all()` and when you iterate it then you call `services` for each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit strange, but it can easily be done if you don't think of the pivot table as a pivot table, but as an `AppService`.

So what you can do is create a model for it, probably named `AppService`.  In that model, you would then have 2 `belongsTo()` relationships.  One for `App` and one for `Service`.

Then you can query your pivot table directly and use those relationships to get what you need.

```
$appServices = AppService::all();
foreach($appServices as $appService) {
    echo $appService->app->description;
    echo $appService->service->description;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and I can return data from the pivot table but the relationship does not seem to be working using belongsTo

Comment: nevermid, i neeeded to add foreign keys